# Reading files from FTP using libcurl

Tags: c, ftp, libcurl

I am writing an application for reading files from FTP server using `libcurl`. After reading all about this library I came to know that I can only download files from FTP server to my local machine, and then read them.

I want to know is there anything define in libcurl so that I can only read files from FTP server, because I have a very limited space in my local device to store files.

this is my approach till now

```
int establish_connection_to_ftp_server(char *uname_pass, char *url,char *filePath,char *err)
{
CURL *curl = NULL;
CURLcode res = -1;
FILE *ftpfile = NULL;
char error_disp[100] = {0};

ftpfile = fopen(filePath,"wb"); /* b is binary, needed on win32 */ 
if(ftpfile==NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to create file\n");
    return -1;
}

show_frame_progress("Establishing Connection to server...");
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, uname_pass);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, ftpfile);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func_upload);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
fclose(ftpfile); /* close the local file */

if((int)res != 0)
{
    sprintf(error_disp,"Unable to connect to server ..\nCurl Error : %d \n%s",res,curl_easy_strerror(res));
    strcpy(err,error_disp);

    return -1;
}
return (int)res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` option is `fwrite` (which, of course, writes data to a file). You can create your own function with the same signature as `fwrite`, and set it as the value of that option. Then libcurl would call your function with the data it downloaded, and you can do whatever you want with it.